# Moving around a scaled container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make it so that the container can be zoomed in and moved around it. At a slight approximation, everything works as it should. But the closer I get, the more difficult it becomes to move around the container, and if I get very close, the container starts moving in the opposite direction from my finger at all. What could this be related to?

```
class _Canvas extends State<Canvas> {
  double canvasScale = 1.0;
  double baseCanvasScale = 1.0;
  Offset canvasOffset = Offset.zero;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onScaleStart: (details) {
          baseCanvasScale = canvasScale;
        },
        onScaleUpdate: (details) {
          setState(() {
            canvasOffset = Offset(
              canvasOffset.dx + details.focalPointDelta.dx,
              canvasOffset.dy + details.focalPointDelta.dy,
            );
            canvasScale = baseCanvasScale * details.scale;
          });
        },
        child: Transform.translate(
          offset: canvasOffset,
          child: Transform.scale(
            scale: canvasScale,
            origin: canvasOffset,
            child: GridPaper(
              divisions: 2,
              subdivisions: 2,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueGrey)),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    ElementOnCanvas(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tried [MatrixGestureDetector](https://pub.dev/documentation/matrix_gesture_detector/latest/matrix_gesture_detector/MatrixGestureDetector-class.html) ?

Comment: No,whose is its advantage over the usual GestureDetector?

Comment: see https://pub.dev/documentation/matrix_gesture_detector/latest/